# how to implement menu navigation in polymer js

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I am new to polymer js

I tried simple polymer application using menu navigation for home ,about and gallery page

index.html page

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js">
    </script>  
    <script type="module" src="src/menu.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="src/aboutus.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="src/home.js"></script>
     <script type="module" src="src/gallery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <menu  class='menu'></menu>
    <home  class='home'></home> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Menu component

```
import {LitElement, html} from '../node_modules/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js';
export class Menu extends LitElement { 
  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

  _render({}) {
    return html`  <a name="view1" href="/home">Home</a>  
          <a name="view2" href="/about">About Us</a>< 
          <a name="view3" href="/galery">Gallery</a>  `;
  }    
} 
customElements.define('menu', Menu);
```

home page

```
export class Home extends LitElement { 
  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

  _render({}) {
    return html` <div> Home </div>`;
  }    
} 
customElements.define('home', Home);
```

about and gallery page have same as home component.
In menu we have link for all the 3 pages. need to displayed each of he page on right hand side on click of each link.

In default home page displayed in index.html.On click of the link about need to show about us page  and on click of the link gallery need to show gallery page.

Comment: Looks like Lit (`extends LitElement`), not Polymer. You need a router element. Google "lit routing".